# Yii: How to define parent object to related childs?

Tags: php, yii, parent, relation

2 Tables: threads and comments (e.g.) => Thread & Comment models

Thread.php

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'comments'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'thread_id'),
    );
}
```

How to define property parent Thread object for each comment child?

Something like this:

```
$model = Thread::model()->with('comments')->findAll();
foreach($model->comments as $comment)
  echo $model->id == $comment->thread->id; // 1
```

P.S. Sorry for my English, I know it's so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define this rule in your `Comment` model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
       'thread'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Thread', 'thread_id'),
    );
```

}

This means each Comment belongs to just ONE thread. 
Now, with this structure, you can do the following:

```
$comments = Comment::model()->with("thread")->findAll();
foreach($comments as $comment)
     ...
```

Comment: Is not it will make 2 queries? We already have a model Thead, and if we use 'thread' relation we get it from DB again?

Comment: I'm already have Thread, it's view action. View of Thread, i need to find Thread first cuz comments mb doesn't exists